# Startup page, new tab page, default search engine - Safari Extension Development

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

Am trying to do three things. Was able to do this in Chrome and Firefox by creating extensions, and that was pretty easy. But am stuck with creating the extension for Safari for these three things:

1. **Custom startup page** : When the browser is opened for the time, it should open a specific webpage by default (in Chrome, its `chrome_settings_overrides` --> `startup_pages`)
2. **Custom page for new tab** : When a new tab is created, I want to display a custom webpage (in Chrome, its `chrome_url_overrides`)
3. **Custom search engine** : When user searches for something, the default search engine used should be the one that I set through code  (in Chrome, its `chrome_settings_overrides` --> `search_provider`)

I tried going through the documentation. But couldn't find any hints.

Any suggestions or how to make this happen? Or is it completely not possible in Safari?